# jQuery click handlers firing once when trying to use object tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having problems with the code below:

```
$('#thing1').on('click',function() {
    writeNewHtml(parm1, 550, 925);
});
```

This works everytime unless I am trying to use an object tag like below:

```
function writeNewHtml(parm1, height, width) {
     $('#div').html("object/embed tag");
}
```

So my question is, is there any reason as to when using the object tag it writes the inner html only once, but if I use any other tag it works as expected?

Comment: what's not working? are there errors? does it just do nothing?

Comment: There's no question being asked here.

Comment: what does your error console say?

Comment: No error being fired in firebug

Comment: @AndrewSehr Why are you rolling back the formatting changes people are  trying to help you with?

Comment: @Znarkus Not meaning to forgot to post question, so I put that in. Sorry for any inconvience.

Comment: @AndrewSehr Can you reproduce the error using http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: @Znarkus : we can use the .add().appendTo() to add the html. anyways I thought the .html() would not be able to bind an object. It does bind one with the DOM. is working perfectly fine

Comment: @Znarkus - Sorry it took so long people keep coming into my office.  Anyways http://jsfiddle.net/ajsehr/2KdRC/8/

Comment: @AndrewSehr Wait, you have an _entire_ office?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ajsehr/2KdRC/8/), you can see that you have used "selectable" plugin before binding the onClick event. This makes any other onclick bindings to that object obsolete. **Removing the following code** will get it to work but you will not be able to use the selectable plugin anymore on the 'Thing 1' and 'Thing 2' elements :

```
$('#thing1').selectable();
$('#thing2').selectable();
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of anyway I could get it to work?  I took the selectable off and it worked properly, but I would like the selecteable to be able to use .click.

Comment: Why do you intend to use the 'selectable' plugin ? the reason would help me think better..

Comment: Basically I have an accordion with a list of values, and when a value is clicked then a flash file (this is out of my control) is loaded

Comment: And why is the 'selectable' plugin coming into picture ? i mean to ask the reason behind using that plugin.